# The error of composite trapezoidal rule is larger than the error of simple trapezoidal rule

Tags: numerical-methods

I know that the composite trapezoidal rule (with $n$ nodes) is the generalization of the trapezoidal rule (with only tow nodes), so the composite one is more accurate than the other.

But actually, when I approximate $\int_{0}^{2} e^{2x}\sin(3x) dx$ using the simple trapezoidal rule I've got $-15.255569$, then the actual error equals: $1.041592$.

And when I approximate this integral using the composite rule with $n=4$ I've got $-11.753893$, then the actual error equals $2.460084$. Why does this happen?

Comment: No, I don't think people will want to guess what you are talking about. Giving those results without even mentioning what are the values of $a$ and $b$ you were using is still more funny than most questions on this site.

Comment: Also, describe your calculation process. Perhaps you will find some error, missed detail during that write-up. Also look up the Shannon and related sampling theorems. To get meaningful results with 1 interval, you need $b-a\le \pi3$.

Comment: Using the trapezoidal rule:
$\int_{0}^{2}e^{2x}sin(3x) dx=(h/2)[f(0)+f(2)]$ where$h=2$
$\int_{0}^{2}e^{2x}sin(3x) dx=1(0-15255569)=-15.255569$
so the actual error equals: $|14.213977-15.255569|=1.041592$
Using the composite trapezoidal rule with $n=4$
$\int_{0}^{2}e^{2x}sin(3x) dx=(h/2)[f(0)+2(f(0.5)+f(1)+f(1.5))+f(2)]$
where $h=0.5$
$\int_{0}^{2}e^{2x}sin(3x) dx=-11.753893$
and the actual error equals: $|-11.753893+14.213977|=2.460084$

Comment: The sampling rate is too low. To get a meaningfull approximation of the function with the samples you will need at least 6 intervals per period, or in other words, the sub-intervals should at most be $\p/9$ long ($\pi/3$ to satisfy sampling theorems as the most extreme condition), thus one or 4 intervals are not in the working area of the composite trapezoidal rule.

Comment: Please add relevant information by editing the question. This makes the question more complete and is better readable.

Comment: Ok, thank you LutzL.

Answer (score 3):

There is no theorem that says "for every function, the composite trapezoidal rule is more accurate than the simple trapezoidal rule".  It is true that  **in most situations**, using more nodes will produce more accurate results. Indeed, suppose $f$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, and let $E_n$ be the error of the trapezoidal rule with $n$ nodes. Then it is true that
$$
E_n\to 0\quad \text{as } \ n\to\infty
$$ 
but this does not mean that the sequence $E_n$ is **decreasing**.  It is quite possible for the error to become larger, then smaller, then larger again, then smaller again.

For another example, consider the integral 
$$
\int_0^1 (9x^2-5x^4)\,dx = 2
$$
The simple trapezoidal rule gives $(f(0)+f(1))/2 = (0+4)/2 = 2$, which is exactly correct. The rules with more nodes have some error: for example,
$$
\frac{f(0)+2f(1/2)+f(1)}{4} \approx 1.96875,  \quad 
$$
and I calculated that the composite rule with $n$ nodes has error
$$
\frac{n(n-2)}{6n^4}
$$ 
So in this example, the simple trapezoidal rule is strictly more accurate than the composite rule for any number of nodes $n>2$. It just happens to be so lucky for this specific function on this specific interval.